# Push notifications not working unless it's on TestFlight or AppStore

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm having problems with push notifications on development. I used APN Tester and this is what I get in return:

```
Connected to server gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com  
Set SSL connection  
Set peer domain name gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com  
Keychain Opened  
Certificate  data  for Apple Push Services: com.boardinc.Board initialized successfully  
Failure creating sec identity, error code -25300  
Failure creating client certificate, error code -50  
Failure performing handshake, error code -9824  
Token: <0c6586f1 3933b8df 5da790a4 dd82e6c6 6cd7245e f27590c1 8c8ede44 53d8912d>  
Failed with sending data to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 with ERROR: -9806, error code -9806  
Disconnected from server gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
```

I can't seem to find any reason why the security identity is not being created.

I tried doing this with Release and Debug tokens with same result. Gateway Development and AdHoc/Production. No success.

Now, push notifications work just fine on TestFlight and in the AppStore. I don't know where can I start. Any suggestions?

Thank you very much.

Comment: First you are using the apple sandbox which means you can only test with development builds of your app (i.e. build and install directly via Xcode), any other combination won't work. Secondly have you checked you are supplying the correct dev push certificate to  APN Tester? If you look at the error messages they are failing very early on, indicating a signing/certificate error.

Comment: Hi. The app is being built and installed through Xcode, as Debug. And yes, I only have one push certificate. I just revoked it and I'm trying to reset my certificates.

Comment: If the app is already in the app store you've just revoked the certificate you will need to use the new one in the server (you need a dev cert for your testing and a prod cert for use with the app in the app store)

Comment: The one that was revoked was the dev one. The production certificate is still up. I will use the new dev one for testing since the previous one wasn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So guys if any of you are having the same issue, the solution is as follows:

- Wiped clean the developer certificate and create a new one
  associated all provisioning profiles to new certificate
- Load up new provisioning profiles in xCode
- Rebuid SSL handshake .pem file (tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial)